# Custom event handler in Unfolding Maps

Tags: event-handling, maps, processing

I am using [Unfolding Maps](http://unfoldingmaps.org) in [Processing](https://www.processing.org).
The following map works correctly:

```
UnfoldingMap map = new UnfoldingMap(this, new OpenStreetMap.OpenStreetMapProvider());
EventDispatcher eventDispatcher = MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map)
```

The issue is that I want to create a custom handler for pan/zoom events to trigger other events in my application. For example, I would like to detect panning and zooming actions in the map to run queries in the background based on the current coordinates, while preserving the default panning/zooming behaviour.

In other web mapping platforms this is trivial (e.g. [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events)), but I can't find any tutorial/reference in UnfoldingMaps.

Any pointers?

Comment: Can you say a bit more about what you intend to do? Certainly you are able to create a custom handler. But when you also want to preserve the default, this might interfere with your custom one.

Comment: I've added more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfolding provides a `mapChanged` event, similar to `mouseClicked` and other event handler in Processing's simplified event system. There, you can implement your background query stuff. You can even check and react to the specific `MapEvent` (even though a bit tedious).

Take a look at this [MapChangedApp example](https://github.com/tillnagel/unfolding/blob/master/examples/de/fhpotsdam/unfolding/examples/events/MapChangedApp.java).

You could also do it via a custom event handler, if you want, but this should be sufficient for your use case. Let me know if you plan to do something else.